# Update version iTunes Connect - Between 22 - 29 December

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

Is it possible to update a version in iTunes Connect between 22-29 December? If it is, could somebody tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question and hence it is off-topic. This question is based on whether such support is available on particular dates or not.

Comment: This question needs to be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with whether a service is available at particular dates, for which only the officials can answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the Apple announced they are closed between 22-29 December. You will not be able to upload new version of your app.

You could have easily found this yourself by check the link about why they are closed: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process#68611491

> **What iTunes Connect, Application Loader, and Transporter features are
>   unavailable during the holiday closure?**
>   From December 22 to December
>   29, 2015, the following features will be unavailable:
>
> - App submissions for new apps and app updates
> - App bundle submissions for new bundles and bundles updates
> - In-App Purchase submissions
> - TestFlight submissions for external testing
>
> All other features, and access to iTunes Connect, will still work.

Answer (score 0):

From December 22 to December 29, 2015, the following features will be unavailable:

App submissions for new apps and app updates

..........

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process#68611491

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Apple will not allow to submit apps. Please find attached screen shot of iTunes Connect for same.

What iTunes Connect, Application Loader, and Transporter features are unavailable during the holiday closure?

```
From December 22 to December 29, 2015, the following features will be unavailable:

App submissions for new apps and app updates
App bundle submissions for new bundles and bundles updates
In-App Purchase submissions
TestFlight submissions for external testing
All other features, and access to iTunes Connect, will still work.
```

Hope it will help you.